# Leer libreria JS puro en Ionic4 - Integración MercadoPago

Tags: mercadopago, ionic4

Siguiendo la documentación de MercadoPago, la única forma de integrar sus funciones con Ionic es a través de la API en Javascript puro ([link](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/payments/api/receiving-payment-by-card/)). Estoy teniendo problemas importando la librería ya que mi APP no la reconoce.

Agregue la librería en mi index.html y debajo las funciones en JS, pero no se ejecutan:

```
<ion-header>
<script src="https://secure.mlstatic.com/sdk/javascript/v1/mercadopago.js"></script>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>mercadopado</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
</ion-content>

<script>
  Mercadopago.setPublishableKey("TEST-b3d5b663-664a-4e8f-b759-de5d7c12ef8f");
    debugger;
  Mercadopago.getIdentificationTypes();

</script>
```

También intente importarlo dentro de Angular7 en el file angular.json pero sin éxito:

```
"scripts": ["https://secure.mlstatic.com/sdk/javascript/v1/mercadopago.js"],
```

¿Existe alguna forma de importar una librería JS y usarla en mi proyecto Ionic? ¿Estoy haciendo algo incorrecto?

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo uso en ionic4 y funciona perfecto. Tenés que agregar el script en `index.html` (vos decis que lo agregaste en index.html, pero el código que pones no corresponde a index.html).

Y, en el componente que vayas a usarlo, (en el .ts), ponés fuera de la clase:
`declare var Mercadopago: any;`

Saludos!

Comment: Tengo una consulta sobre `declare var Mercadopago: any;`
Eso lo reconoce ionic, pero por ejemplo al llamar a `Mercadopago.getIdentificationTypes();` dentro de ngOnInit o el constructor siempre devuelve undefined. Tenes algun codigo de ejemplo de implementacion? Gracias de antemano

Comment: No tengo ningún código de ejemplo para compartirte, pero si vos subís un repositorio con lo que tenes, puedo ayudarte.

Para el caso del `getIdentificationTypes` tengo:
```
if (Mercadopago) {
      Mercadopago.setPublishableKey(environment.mercadopago.publicKey);

      Mercadopago.getIdentificationTypes((status, response) => {
        if (status !== 200) {
          // error...
        }
        // handle response...
      });
    } else {
      // error...
    }
```

Saludos!